# Hive UDF with Python error code return code 20001

Tags: python, hive, user-defined-functions

```html
import sys
import datetime
count = 0
try:
        for line in sys.stdin:
                orders= line.split(',')
                order_id = orders[0]
                order_time = orders[1]
                order_status = orders[3]
                order_status = order_status[:-1]
                order_date = order_time.split(" ")[0]
                #print '\t'.join([order_id, str(order_status)])
                if order_status == 'COMPLETE' and order_date[:4] == '2014':
                #print('{0} is {1}'.format(order_id,order_status))
                #print(order_date[:4])
                        count+=1
        print(count)
except:
        print sys.exc_info()
```

I'm learning how to execute simple user-defined functions on
hive with python
I'm trying to execute the above python code on my hive table which contains comma-separated values
I tried cat orders.txt| python newworld.py and the output counts values perfectly. However, i'm unable to get the same output from the hive

error code below

```
[Error 20001]: An error occurred while reading or writing to your custom script. It may have crashed with an error.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.processOp(ScriptOperator.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:497)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely late and hopefully you've solved this issue already, but for reference to those who have come across this: even if the original file is delimited by commas, Hive will delimit them by tabs instead. Thus, if you replaced the ',' with '\t' like:

```
orders= line.split('\t')
```

assuming the rest of the code runs when you were debugging it directly with the txt file, it should work.

p.s. Unfortunately, I have never found the error codes to be helpful